# Distinguish a character string from a datetime literal

Tags: sql, sql-server

From [SQL Server data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) documentation, it gives the following examples for character strings and datetime:

The following are examples of datetime constants:

```
'December 5, 1985'
'5 December, 1985'
'851205'
'12/5/98'
```

And the following are examples of character strings:

```
'Cincinnati'
'O''Brien'
'Process X is 50% complete.'
'The level for job_id: %d should be between %d and %d.'
"O'Brien"
```

How then does someone know if the text `'2-Dec 2018'` or `'Dec 500, 2014'` is a string or a datetime type?

Comment: You can't.......

Comment: More context would be helpful, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: the type of your target determines what the string contains. if your target is a string, then it's a string, if it's a datetime, a conversion is performed. To avoid issues, there are some strings which are better to use for dates than others, for example YYYYMMDD is good, while YYYY-MM-DD and friends are ambigious and maybe not always parse correctly depending on the server settings

Comment: and if you just select 'anystring' it will always be string or varchar

Comment: May I add that the datetime examples used in the documentation should not be used in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context.  There is no way to tell the difference based on the syntax of the constant.  However, the compiler will interpolate the type from the context -- if there is no context it will assume string.

For example, if you are comparing to a date -- it will assume the constant is a date, if you are comparing to a string it will assume a string.  If you are inserting int to a table or modifying a table it will look at the type of the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for a date via `try_convert()`, but this may not be 100%

`try_convert()` will return a NULL if the conversion fails.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('December 5, 1985')
,('5 December, 1985')
,('851205')
,('12/5/98')
,('SomeString')
,('25')
 
Select *
      ,IsDate = try_convert(date,SomeCol)
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol             IsDate
December 5, 1985    1985-12-05
5 December, 1985    1985-12-05
851205              1985-12-05
12/5/98             1998-12-05
SomeString          NULL
25                  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have have a mechanism¹ to specify a date literal, `'December 5, 1985'` is always a string literal representing `varchar(16)` data type, 16 would be the number of characters in the literal ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KcZBborC)).

That being said, this string literal will be implicitly converted to date/time/datetime/etc **data type** if the context requires a conversion. Examples include comparison with datetime (datetime has higher precedence than varchar), insert into or update a datetime column, declaring a datetime variable and so on. This does not prevent a query such as `where datetime_col = 'foobar'` from compiling, you get error on runtime.

---

¹ ANSI standard does allow you to write date literals using `DATE '1985-12-05'` syntax.